# Saving callee-saved registers results into segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I'm trying to save callee-saved registers.
In the following code I only try to save `%r15` (the behavior is the same when other callee-saved registers are saved, one or all).

```
 .data
     hello: .string "Hello"
     format: .asciz "%s\n"
 .text
     .global _main
 _main:
   pushq %rbp
   pushq %r15
   leaq format(%rip), %rdi
   leaq hello(%rip), %rsi
   callq _printf
   popq  %r15
   popq  %rbp
   movq  $0, %rax
   retq
```

The result is `Segmentation fault: 11`. When `pushq %r15` and `popq %r15` are commented, the program outputs `Hello` as expected.

What's the reason for the Segmentation fault? The problem is reproducible on my Ubuntu and OS X systems, but not on Ubuntu subsystem in Windows.

The code is compiled as `gcc test.s`. On OS X:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: You misaligned the stack. It needs to be 16 byte aligned as per calling convention. Also you should zero `%al` before calling `printf` (means the number of SSE registers used for a varargs function). Consult the ABI docs for details.

Comment: @Jester, Thank you very much!

Comment: AL is probably non-zero, so the library implementation of `printf` is probably doing 8 `movaps` instructions to store the XMM0..7 registers to the stack.  Or maybe current OS X `printf` simply assumes stack alignment for something else, and would fault on a misaligned stack even with `al=0`.